# best token analyzer to index and query in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a repository of c++ code in a database and would like to index it in SOLR. What is the best token analyzer I should use to index and later query in SOLR?

I've tried a few different token analyzers, and was thinking to set up the schema to delimit by spaces,periods,other special characters, etc.

Is there a better way to go about indexing code like this?

Comment: This entirely depends on how how you expect to search/find things. When someone searches for hello, do you want to find hello++, hello; !hello, (hello), etc. Once you have a definition, you'd have a much easier time coming up with analyzers to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with a simple configuration, and add further for any specific needs :-

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory ... "/>       
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>    
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

[WhitespaceTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory) - Whitespace Tokenizer to break the tokens at whitespace
[StopFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory)  - Stop Filter to remove common terms in the source code, which would appear in all the files.
[LowerCaseFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory) - lower case to make search case independent.